# Event model or schema in event store

Tags: events, event-sourcing, json-api

Events in an event store (event sourcing) are most often persisted in a serialized format with versions to represent a changed in the model or schema for an event type. I haven't been able to find good documentation showing the actual model or schema for an actual event (often `data` table in event store schema if using a RDBMS) but understand that ideally it should be generic.

**What are the most basic fields/properties that should exist in an event?**

I've contemplated using json-api as a specification for my events but perhaps that's too "heavy". The benefits I see are flexibility and maturity.

**Am I heading down the "wrong path"?**

Any well defined examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add a tag such as .net please unless you intentionally want a generic answer? also event-store means neventstore - if you mean Greg Young's GES, there's `get-event-store`

Comment: An event store and event schema is not dependent on either .net or neventstore.

Comment: I'm extremely well aware of that. The point is that for better or for worse, the tag event-store does not mean what you think it means - it means a .NET store [that's generally used in a SQL DB]. I have no issue with you wanting a generic answer either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've contemplated using json-api as a specification for my events but perhaps that's too "heavy". The benefits I see are flexibility and maturity.
>
> Am I heading down the "wrong path"?

Don't overlook forward and backward compatibility.

You should plan to review Greg Young's book on [event versioning](https://leanpub.com/esversioning); it doesn't directly answer your question, but it does cover a lot about the basics of interpreting an event.

Short answer: pretty much everything is optional, because you need to be able to change it later.

You should also review Hohpe's Enterprise Integration Patterns, in particular his work on [messaging](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/toc.html), which details a lot of cases you may care about.

de Graauw's [Nobody Needs Reliable Messaging](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging) helped me to understan an important point.

> To summarize: if reliability is important on the business level, do it on the business level.

So while there are some interesting bits of meta data tracking that you may want to do, the domain model is really only going to look at the *data*; and that is going to tend to be specific to your domain.

You *also* have the fun that the representation of events that you use in the service that produces them may not match the representation that it shares with other services, and in particular may not be the same message that gets broadcast.

I worked through an exercise trying to figure out what the minimum amount of information necessary for a subscriber to look at an event to understand if it cares.  My answers were an id (have I seen this specific event before?), a token that tells you the semantic meaning of the message (is that something I care about?), and a location (URI) to get a richer representation if it is something I care about.

But outside of the domain -- for example, when you are looking at the system as a whole trying to figure out what is going on, having correlation identifiers and causation identifiers, time stamps, signatures of the source location, and so on stored in a consistent location in the meta data can be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Just modelling with basic types that map to Json to write as you would for an API can go a long way.

You can spend a lot of time generating overly complex models if you throw too much tooling at it - things like Apache Thrift and/or Protocol Buffers (or derived things) will provide all sorts of IDL mechanisms for you to generate incidental complexity with.

In .NET land and many other platforms, if you namespace the types you can do various projections from the types

Personally, I've used records and DUs in F# as a design and representation tool

- you get intellisense, syntax hilighting, and types you can use from F# or C# for free
- if someone wants to look, `types.fs` has all they need